# Convert ZonedDatetime to String

Tags: java, android

I am receiving JSON object containing a time in following format.

```
...
"start_time": "2020-12-30T17:30:00Z",
...
```

I've parsed it and assigned to `ZonedDateTime`

```
ZonedDateTime start_time = ZonedDateTime.parse(jsonObject.getString("start_time"));
```

Now I'd like to show it in `String` with users' device's local time zone.

I believe json time is in UTC zone. So users in Hongkong would see +8 offset, while users in Los Angeles would see -8 offset. So they would see as follows.

Users in HK: 2020-12-31 01:30

Users in LA: 2020-12-30 09:30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those devices had configured the time zone correctly, you can use

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm");
System.out.println(start_time.format(formatter.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())));
```

to get your result

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Instant
.parse( "2020-12-30T17:30:00Z" )
.atZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() )  // Or specify: ZoneId.of( "Asia/Hong_Kong" )
.format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm" ) )
```

See this code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/XjUzx3).

> 2020-12-31 01:30

## Details

Your input `"2020-12-30T17:30:00Z"` is in standard ISO 8601 format. The `Z` on the end means an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minute-seconds, and is pronounced “Zulu”. We also refer to a Zulu date-time as being "in UTC".

You should parse such inputs as an `Instant`, not the `ZonedDateTime` seen in your Question.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2020-12-30T17:30:00Z" ) ;
```

To see that same moment through the wall-clock time (offset) used by the people of a particular region, specify a time zone (`ZoneId`) to produce a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zHongKong = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Hong_Kong" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtHongKong = instant.atZone( zHongKong ) ;
```

…and…

```
ZoneId zLosAngeles = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtLosAngeles = instant.atZone( zLosAngeles ) ;
```

All three objects refer to the same moment, the same point on the timeline.

To produce strings, call `toString`.

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/PHkaAU).

> Instant.toString(): 2020-12-30T17:30:00Z
>
> zdtHongKong.toString(): 2020-12-31T01:30+08:00[Asia/Hong_Kong]
>
> zdtLosAngeles.toString(): 2020-12-30T09:30-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]

To produce text in certain formats, use `DateTimeFormatter` class. That class can also automatically localize the generate text.

```
Locale locale = new Locale( "en" , "HK" ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdtHongKong.format( f ) ;
```

> 31/12/2020, 1:30 AM

All of this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more. And search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.